# Python, why is the enumerated list not changing the object in 3D View Property Shelf, while it's working in the Tool shelf

Tags: python, scripting, panel

I wrote the following script to test creating a new panel in the properties shelf in 3D view (the one that toggles visibility using <kbd>N</kbd>). 
The script is working for creating object, but the enumerated list isn't changing the object as I'm expecting it to, while it's working in the Tool shelf in 3D view, or using <kbd>F6</kbd>.
What's wrong with my code?

```
import bpy
from bpy.props import *


class whatever_OP(bpy.types.Operator):

    bl_idname = "object.set_enum_prop"
    bl_label = "Whatever"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER','UNDO'}

    def update_enum (self,context):
        self= [('0','Cube',""),
            ('1','Ico_sphere',""),
            ('2','Cone',"")
            ]

    Axis = [('0','Cube',""),
            ('1','Ico_sphere',""),
            ('2','Cone',"")
            ]

    enum_prop = EnumProperty \
        (
        items = Axis,
        name ="Add",
        description = "Set the Axis",
        #default = '2',
        update = update_enum
        )

    def execute(self,context):

        enum_prop = int(self.enum_prop)

        if enum_prop == 0:
            bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()
        elif enum_prop == 1:
            bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_ico_sphere_add()
        elif enum_prop == 2:
            bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cone_add()
        else:
            print ("None")

        return {"FINISHED"}

class whatever_panel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_label = "Whatever Panel"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        if bpy.context.object.type == 'MESH' :
            return True

    def draw(self, context):

        layout = self.layout
        layout.operator("object.set_enum_prop", "Add Mesh")
        layout.prop(context.scene, "set_enum_prop") 



#register

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(whatever_panel)
    bpy.utils.register_class(whatever_OP)
    bpy.types.Object.set_enum_prop = whatever_OP.enum_prop

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(whatever_panel)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(whatever_OP)
    del bpy.types.Object.set_enum_prop

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: I think it would help if you could add information as to what you are expecting to happen vs what actually happens.

Comment: @RayMairlot as I mentioned in my question, I was expecting that changing the value of the enumerated list would change the object in the view, I'm sorry if I couldn't put it in a better way, English isn't my native language, and I'm a novice in programming, I don't know how to describe it in a technically correct way, that's why I included the code in my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a few things wrong with your code. Here it is corrected for you to compare:

```
import bpy
from bpy.props import *


Axis = [('0','Cube',""),
        ('1','Ico_sphere',""),
        ('2','Cone',"")
        ]

class whatever_OP(bpy.types.Operator):

    bl_idname = "object.set_enum_prop"
    bl_label = "Whatever"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER','UNDO'}


    def execute(self,context):

        enum_prop = context.scene.set_enum_prop

        if enum_prop == '0':
            bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()
        elif enum_prop == '1':
            bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_ico_sphere_add()
        elif enum_prop == '2':
            bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cone_add()
        else:
            print ("None")

        return {"FINISHED"}

class whatever_panel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_label = "Whatever Panel"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return bpy.context.active_object != None and bpy.context.object.type == 'MESH'

    def draw(self, context):

        layout = self.layout
        layout.operator("object.set_enum_prop", "Add Mesh")
        layout.prop(context.scene, "set_enum_prop") 


#register

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(whatever_panel)
    bpy.utils.register_class(whatever_OP)
    bpy.types.Scene.set_enum_prop = EnumProperty \
        (
        items = Axis,
        name ="Add",
        description = "Set the Axis",
        #default = '2'
        )

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(whatever_panel)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(whatever_OP)
    del bpy.types.Scene.set_enum_prop

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

I don't know if you actually wanted the property on the object or the scene, as you used both(one pf the problems). So I just went with scene.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I appreciate you taking the time to fix my code, It's working as expected, I really still don't understand fully how this fixes things, but I'll fiddle with it further more, Blender API documentation is really like a puzzle, it's hard to find the right documentation for many topics. It would be great if you can edit your question to explain more the wrong code that you fixed.

Comment: The issue I'm having now is updating the enum_prop value, since you removed the update function and the update property in the enumerated list, I can't get it to update. Is there a problem with the update functionality, it worked when I put the panel in the tool shelf in view 3D. May I ask why did you consider it a wrong code and removed it in your answer?

Comment: The update didn't do anything. Your property would have worked without it. Can I ask why you want the enum in the panel and the operator properties? Is it just so you can change the enum before the operator is run?

Comment: The example I posted here is for testing, since I'm learning Blender API, I needed to know how to create the panels with dynamic enum lists in order to use it in an addon I'm working on, I tested it first as a view 3d menu item, so the enum list appeared in the Tool shelf, and in the Object menu, then I tried to create a panel in the Property shelf , I thought it would behave the same, created object would dynamically change following the enum list value. You actually provided me with a better option, comparing your answer to my code, I understand UI much better. Cheers!